# Bluetooth Low Energy Background Data (iBeacons)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am currently writing an application that uses `BTLE` to pass small strings of data between 2 or more phones.

Currently in the foreground I am passing though: `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` and `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey`. I am able to recover (via NSLog) the string passed through the CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey when the app is in the foreground.

However when the app is in the background, the `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` is not passed through. The `BTLE UUID` is still passed through along with the `RSSI` integer, the `CBAdvDataChannel` and the `CBAdvDataIsConnectable`.

After combing through what seems to be an unending circle called Apple Documentation, I have found no way to pass a small string while the app is in the background. It seems to me that they wouldn't allow `BTLE` in the background if there was no way to pass data.

My question is does anyone know a workaround to pass data in the background with BTLE or a method that may allow me to do so? Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Edit: I should make clear that the Library I am trying this with is called Vicinity https://github.com/Instrument/Vicinity which uses `CoreBluetooth` to get around the background limitations of `CoreLocation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some use out of this project, which lets devices share arrays of strings (such as userIDs) over Bluetooth LE, even while backgrounded: [SimpleShare](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)

It can still share data while the app is in the background because it only sends the data when a device subscribes to the advertised bluetooth characteristic by changing the characteristic's value to send each piece of data. You don't need the name key to transfer the information.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

iBeacons are not made for transmitting data between two devices. BLE beacons are used to determine the current location of an iDevice. to unique identify the beacon it broadcasts the advertising data, wich contains an uuid(32 hexdigits), a major(4 hexdigits) and a minor number(4 hexdigits). thats all. if you want to transfer data you have to use any other service.

Comment: All i need is something like a major or minor value passed through in the background. The problem becomes when the app is in the background. Using CoreLocation and the traditional iBeacon protocol as you described is turned off in the background and restarted in the foreground. Using CoreBluetooth, you can still emit beacons in the background (the protocol may be a tad different) but it severely limits the data you can pass through. If you are familiar with something like FitBit http://www.fitbit.com/ I believe they pass BTLE data in the background.

Comment: Or, If there is another bluetooth technology that allows for low power data transmission without the need for pairing, I'd be open to ideas too. Though I am not sure there is a way to do that.

Comment: we would be fine with receiving the major and minor while the device is in the bg , but we cant even get that as of now. We just need something, anything! that will allow us to tell 1 device from another that can scale aka we could potentially have have 1000s of users each broadcasting their own unique id (the major/minor would do just fine for us i think IF we could get it)

Comment: once again: beacon are not made for data transmission. its made for, primaraly, indoor location services.

Comment: You can of course get the major/minor number while in the background - that's the whole point of the iBeacon concept.  Potentially you can use (part of) those as an index in to a table of predefined messages.  If you are not getting the major/minor, something is wrong with your implementation.